# How do you see a client authorization certificate in Chrome devtools?

Tags: ssl, google-chrome-devtools, client-certificates, ssl-client-authentication

Is there a way to see a client authentication certificate in devtools? While Chrome asks me what cert I want to send, I don't see it in the headers anywhere. I assume this is because the TLS setup is handled internally in some way and may not appear here.

Is there a way to see it?

Comment: In HTTPS TLS setup, or *handshaking*, occurs first, before *any* HTTP data is sent. It is during the TLS handshake that certificates are sent. Presumably chrome and other browsers give you ways to examine client certificates,

Comment: Presumably - what's interesting is I found it when it showed up on nginx just fine so it is definitely getting sent but I can't find the corresponding headers in devtools

Comment: It wouldn't be in any header because it's not part of HTTP.

Comment: Well. It's obvious when you say it like that 